# Git: insert commits preserving no-ff history

Tags: git

I have git history like this.

[image]

Then I want to insert 2 commits after commit A (which are ingored at commit B). Like this.

[image]

I tried rebase but it swallows no-fast-forward branch. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What `rebase` command have you tried?

Comment: git checkout A;
git checkout -b temp;
git commit -am "I did something";
git rebase --no-ff temp G. I'm ashamed to revealing my mistake. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) should work, but you might need to add the `--preserve-merges` option:

```
-p
--preserve-merges
```

> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.

Comment: Short, perfect answer